# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint Django

Tags: django, database, django-models

I came up with this problem, when I was creating my app.
So whenever I add first comment the problem doesn't appear, but when I try do it second time I get this error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "tripplanner_discussion_author_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(1)
>   already exists.

I've tried to put `unique=False` to models.py, but it didn't help at all.

models.py

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

views.py

```
class DiscussionView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Discussion
    template_name = 'tripplanner/discussion.html'
    fields = ['text']
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.group = self.trip
        return super(DiscussionView, self).form_valid(form)
```

UPDATE

When I logged to another user, the problem disappeared for one post, then it reoccured. So the problem to solve is to make this author_id unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True

If you check the source code [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#OneToOneField)., it sets the `unique` in **init**.

I think you should use `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOne`.

Comment: You are right, thank you :) I thought that `OneToOne` will work a little bit different here, but I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove `unique = False` then do make migrations & migrate it. if already migrations is there and remove migrations and caches for that applications and remove that id in admin page then do it may work